# error: linker `cc` not found ao tentar compilar arquivo .rs

Tags: compilação, rust, opensuse

Estou tentando compilar um arquivo .rust via terminal do vscode, e recebo esse erro:

```
causticroot@install:~/learning-rust/Book exercises/Hello world> rustc hello_world.rs 
error: linker `cc` not found
  |
  = note: No such file or directory (os error 2)

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Minha versão do rust e do cargo:

```
rustc 1.46.0 (04488afe3 2020-08-24)
cargo 1.46.0 (149022b1d 2020-07-17)
```

Sistema: OpenSUSE leap 15.2 - kde/plasma

Comment: Esse `cc` que está faltando é o _C Compiler_. Você possui algum compilador de C instalado como o GCC ou CLANG?

Comment: Tenho o `build-essential` instalado, que no caso da minha distro é instalado assim: `sudo zypper in cmake`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, instalando :
`sudo zypper in cmake`
`sudo zypper in gcc`